# How do I rotate my fusion laser?

Tags: spacechem

Is the fusion laser in SpaceChem rotatable, or is it always stuck fusing what's on the left into what's on the right (vs. say, up-and-down)?  If it is rotatable, how?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's not rotatable, sadly.  I had one puzzle where I really would have liked it to be up-and-down.

Comment: I’ve got one where I want it to be backwards. `:-(`